# Transferring ERC20 token to a contract using custom function

Tags: erc-20, transfer, transferfrom, erc-20-approve

I have a couple of questions related to transferring ERC20 token to a contract.

I am developing a protocol that has its own token to provide incentive mechanisms. For certain operations I need to lock tokens in the protocol contract.

The traditional way is to use `approve` and then `transferFrom`. But I want to avoid doing this in two txs (for the UX, for the gas, etc). Doing some research I found a lot of proposals that fixes this: ERC2612 (ERC20 + Permit function), ERC-1363, ERC-777, ERC-1155 and many more.

If I had to choose any right now, I would choose ERC2612 `permit` function (Uniswap / MakerDAO solution). But I was wondering, why not to *whitelist* the contract address in the token and use a custom non-standard function to perform the transfer without approval in a single tx. I will attach a simplified token and contract example code below to let you see what I am describing:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {

    modifier onlyProtocolContract() {
        require(_msgSender() == protocolContract, "Only protocol contract can call this function");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_msgSender() == owner, "Only owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    address owner;
    address protocolContract;

    constructor() ERC20("Token", "TKN") {
        owner = _msgSender();
    }

    function setProtocolContractAddress(address _protocolContract) external onlyOwner() {
        protocolContract = _protocolContract;
    }

    function transferToProtocolContract(address _fromAccount, uint256 _amount) external onlyProtocolContract() {
        _transfer(_fromAccount, protocolContract, _amount);
    }
}
```

```
import { SafeMath } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import { Token } from "./Token.sol";

contract Protocol {

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    Token token;

    mapping(address => uint256) stakedBalance;

    constructor(Token _token) {
        token = _token;
    }

    function stake(uint256 _amount) external {
        require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amount, "Token balance below given staking amount");
        token.transferToProtocolContract(msg.sender, _amount);
        stakedBalance[msg.sender] = stakedBalance[msg.sender].add(_amount);
    }

    function unstake(uint256 _amount) external {
        require(stakedBalance[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Staked tokens below given amount to unstake");
        token.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _amount);
        stakedBalance[msg.sender] = stakedBalance[msg.sender].sub(_amount);
    }
}
```

I deployed this solution and it works. So, my questions are:

1. I didn't find anyone implementing this kind of solution. Has something wrong?
2. I concluded that maybe the wrong thing is implementing a single-tx-solution without caring about being reusable by other contracts (for example exchanges). Taking this into account, what solution do you recommend to adopt?
3. What do you think about having the described *whitelisted contract* solution to minimize gas in the protocol and the `permit` function to allow other contracts to perform the transfer in a single transaction too?

Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.